# uWSGI set configuration depending on environment variable

Tags: uwsgi

Please help me understand uWSGI configuration logic. 
I have an environment variable `ENVIRONMENT`. Let's say its values can either be `dev` or `prod`. I want to set configuration options based on value of `ENVIRONMENT`

```
# always executes print statement, doesn't matter what ENVIRONMENT is set to
if-env= ENVIRONMENT
if-opt: %(_)=dev
print = RUNNING %(_)
endif:
endif =

# always executes print statement, doesn't matter what ENVIRONMENT is set to
running = ENVIRONMENT
if-opt: running=dev
print = RUNNING %(_)
endif:
```

I would assume if `ENVIRONMENT` is set to `prod` none of the assignments or `print` statements inside `if-opt` block would execute. But this not the case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
[uwsgi]
if-env = ENVIRONMENT
env = %(_)
endif =
if-not-env = ENVIRONMENT
env = none
endif =
print = RUNNING %(env)
if-opt = env=dev
print = running dev yay
endif =
```

You were using YAML syntax in INI configuration. I also had to take `if-opt` out of `if-env` because it was complaining about recursion. There might be a way to make it shorter, but this works.

Comment: Works indeed. Thanks for your time!